# Shared preference save location address from geolocator

Tags: flutter, caching, path, geolocation, sharedpreferences

i was able to get current location using geolocator, but i want to cache and restore the string address without using lastKnownLocation in geolocator. im using shared preferences but cannot make it work. i used shared preference several times on my other codes, but with geolocator its kind of complicated. and im super new to flutter/dart

code:

```js
  final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;
  Position _currentPosition;
  String _currentAddress;
  String _locationCache;
  String key = "location_cache";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentLocation();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("current location = " + _currentAddress),
            Text("last location = " + __locationCache) // HERE GET STORED DATA ISNT WORKING
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _getCurrentLocation() {
    geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
      });

      _getAddressFromLatLng();
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  _getAddressFromLatLng() async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> p = await geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(
          _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);

      Placemark place = p[0];

      setState(() {
        _currentAddress = "${place.country}";
      });

      saveAddress();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<bool> saveAddress() async { 
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await prefs.setString(key, _currentAddress);
  }

  Future<String> retrieveAddress() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Return String
    return prefs.getString(key) ?? "";
  }

  loadAddress() {
    retrieveAddress().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _locationCache = value;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

heres the working code without _locationCache:

[image]

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution. just replace `loadAddress()` function with

```js
void save() {
    String address = _currentAddress;
    saveAddress(address);
  }

void _updateName(String address) {
  setState(() {
    this.locationCache = address;
  });
}
```

and then put `retrieveAddress().then(updateName)` inside `initState()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you want to accomplish is to store the last address you caught and retrieve it if you don't have gps active. 
To do so you could use [SharedPreferences](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value) or [SQLite](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite), just check the documentation on how to use them.

Comment: i edited the code above with shared preferences included but still no success